# Doesnt display print output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

The below code works well if there is an odd number in the input parameters but when all numbers are even then it doesn't print 'all even'. Any thoughts? I am using Python3.6

```
#Find largest odd number from the given list

x,y,z=2,4,12
if x%2==0:
    x=0
else:
    x=x  
if y%2==0:
    y=0
else:
    y=y
if z%2==0:
    z=0
else:
    z=z
    t=x+y+z
    if t==0:
        print('all even')
    else:
        print(max(x,y,z))
```

Comment: Your indentation is such that the block with `print()` statements is never executed (`z%2==0` is true, so the `else` suite is never reached).

Comment: Each of your `else:` suites are otherwise redundant and can be removed entirely. There is no need to assign `x` back to `x`, for example.

Comment: You don't even have a *list*; if you did, all of this code could be written into one line: `max(i for i in numbers if i % 2 == 0)` - well but you could use `[x, y, z]` there...

Comment: Thanks so much..Just fixed it with your input. My first post on stack over flow and my day 1 with Python. Feeling great to have this kind of support.

Answer (score 0):

The 12%2==0 so it just initializes z=0 and prints nothing.

```
if z%2==0:
    z=0
else:
    z=z
    t=x+y+z
```

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet:

```
>>> x, y, z = 2, 4, 12
>>> x%2, y%2, z%2
(0, 0, 0)
```

shows that `mod 2` of an even number is always 0.

The conditions in your `if` statements are therefore evaluating to `True` in all cases, so the final `else` branch is not entered, and no printing occurs.

You could try this code instead:

```
x, y, z = 2, 4, 12
numbers = (x, y, z)
if any(i%2 for i in numbers):
    print(max(numbers))
else:
    print('all even')
```

or, more succinctly:

```
print(max(numbers) if any(i%2 for i in numbers) else 'all even')
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can work well

```
x,y,z=2,4,12
if x%2==0:
   x=0 
if y%2==0:
   y=0
if z%2==0:
   z=0
t=x+y+z
if t==0:
   print('all even')
else:
   print(max(x,y,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I reformatted some of these lines AND removed lines that were redundant (ie. `else x=x`)

```
x, y, z = 2, 4, 12

if x % 2 == 0:
    x = 0
if y % 2 == 0:
    y = 0
if z % 2 == 0:
    z = 0
```

This line was not properly outdented, which meant it never ran.

```
t = x + y + z

if t == 0:
    print('all even')
else:
    print(max(x,y,z))
```

As was noted by commenters this can all be replaced with some slightly more Pythonic code:

```
numbers = [2, 4, 12]
results = max(0 if i % 2 == 0 else i for i in numbers)
```

This following code basically says... if `results` is anything but zero, print the `results` OTHERWISE print 'all even'

```
if results:          
    print(results)
else:
    print('all even')
```